# Mongo regex | find docs where subarray contains any part of string

Tags: regex, mongodb

I have a relatively simple Mongo collection (named alerts) - which contains multiple sub-array properties with strings.  For example:

```
{
    "alertName":"Test Alert",
    "sources":["hose"],
    "chemicals":["Lead"]
}
```

I am attempting to search this collection where any item in one of the sub-arrays is contained input search string.

For example, given the input string "**Hose Elbow Value Pack**" - if I were to do a regex query on the source subarray - I would expect the document above returned - since "hose" from the sources array is contained within that string.

```
db.alerts.find({sources:{'$in':[/Hose Elbow Value Pack X001ACFNEB/i]})
db.alerts.find({sources:{'$in':[/.*Hose Elbow Value Pack X001ACFNEB.*/i]})
```

Any suggestions would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Create an index for searching.

```
db.alerts.createIndex( { sources: "text" } )
```

Run

```
db.alerts.find( { $text: { $search: "Hose Elbow Value Pack X001ACFNEB" } } )
```

For more help https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/text-search/

Comment: thank you for the suggestion.  i neglected to say that documents in the alert collection have multiple sub array properties (for example:  sources and chemicals).  in some cases i may wish to do the regex search against sources sub-array.  in other instances i may wish to do the regex search against the chemicals sub-array.  so the text search is not optimal in this regards